# Parts of the form disappear when WindowState is set to maximized

Tags: c#, winforms

This problem is happening when the `FormBorderStyle = None` and a button is used to set the `WindowState`. Chunks of the form turn invisible when the form is restored from a minimized state or is maximized from a normal state.

[image: Glitchy maximized winform]

The code for maximizing and minimize:

```
private void MaximizeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
    else
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
}

private void minimize_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

I have failed to recreate this glitch in any other winform based application of mine.
I appreciate the help , hope you all are having a comfortable covid stay.

Comment: Obviously, this is a custom form. We need to see what customizations you made to it. Please [edit] the question and include the relevant parts of the code in the `.designer.cs` file in addition to any relevant form events you're using, if any (e.g., `Form.Paint`, `Form.SizeChanged`, etc.). In short, try to create a [repro].

Comment: Well, you have a fake Caption and Buttons, it could be related to the code that activates the *fake dragging* of the Form and/or the mouse Capture, if you have used that method (overriding WndProc instead of handling the mouse movements). Check the code that handles those Controls first (maybe you're also *painting something*?).

Comment: The only customization I did to the form was to simply set the FormBorderStyle property for the form to none, that's all, I'm not using any events other than the button click events regarding resizing of the font.

Comment: Yes I'm using that WndProc method, but I have another project that also makes use of it, and there's no as such issue in that project. :(

Comment: Never use CreateGraphics() to paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply refresh the window once its state becomes maximized. Unlike WPF, Winforms doesn't have a StateChanged event, so use SizeChanged to detect if the window it's maximized, and refresh it.

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if(WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized) 
           Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I  initially tried to just refresh the form , but you gave me an idea to refresh all the parent panels on sizechanged event , so now it works perfectly ! .